# Can a compliant stateful allocator be unequal to its older copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

The [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) prescribes that an allocator must be equal to its copies, with respect to moves and rebinding. But can it become unequal to its previous state after its member functions are invoked, for example after allocating a value? That is, could this be a compliant allocator?

```cpp
auto allocator_copy = allocator;
std::cout << (allocator == allocator_copy) << std::endl;  // Outputs "1", as prescribed by the standard.
allocator.allocate(1);
std::cout << (allocator == allocator_copy) << std::endl;  // Outputs "0";
```

Comment: Well, equality of allocators show if one can be used to free memory allocated by the other. If this true for the instances, you should return true, otherwise false. I don't think there is a reason to get philosophic about that.

Comment: Where did you get this requirement on the page you reference? It says stateful allocators are allowed to be unequal, and stateful allocators must be supported for C++11.

Comment: @Eugene "`A a1 = a`: Copy-constructs `a1` such that `a1 == a`" The question is - once the two allocators are equal, are they required to be equal for life? May calling a non-const function on one alter it in such a way that it no longer compares equal to the other? The standard doesn't appear to say anything about it, but practically speaking, the equality relation would be rather useless if it could disappear as soon as you try to actually use an allocator. So I expect things to break if one attempts an allocator like this.

Comment: The standard does say that "`a1==a2` returns `true` only if storage allocated from each can be deallocated via the other." Perhaps it could be said that, implicit in this definition, is the requirement that the equality should survive calls to `allocate` and `deallocate`. Otherwise there doesn't appear to be any way to actually make use of the fact that two allocators are equal. The intent seems clear, even if the wording is not 100% precise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point. I can imagine for example a self-owning data structure: `auto x = alloc.allocate(1); x->alloc = std::move(alloc);`. So then `x` can deallocate itself with the moved/copied, equal allocator. But if this is allowed" `auto copy = alloc; x = alloc.allocate(1); x->alloc = std::move(copy);` and `x` then used `copy` to deallocate self, my idea for a stateful allocator won't work

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Would you consider converting your comment into an answer so that I can up-vote it?